# infinitive clause behind passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive-clauses

Are the following examples, infinitive clause following passive voice, be understood to be **in order to**? If not, what do they mean?

> The machine was needed to speed the process.

The machine was needed **in order to** seed the process?

> The information required to make a decision is not provided yet.

The information required **in order to** make a decision is not provided yet?

> He was asked to resolve the dispute.

He was asked **in order to** resolve the dispute?

> He was believed to use our sympathy to reach his goal.

He was believed **in order to** use our sympathy to reach his goal?

Changing **to** to **in order to** helps me understand sentences better, so I am wondering if that works in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your first two sentences work when rephrased as you suggest. Your third and fourth do not.

> He was asked to resolve the dispute.

This means nothing more nor less than what it says. It doesn't say *why* he was asked to resolve the dispute, simply that he was. There is no explicitly stated *purpose* behind the action.

In one scenario, it's possible that the people asking him to resolve the dispute know that he'll never be able to do so. Perhaps they know that the two sides in the conflict will actually kill him instead.

Assuming *that* to be the case, then you could say:

> He was asked to resolve the dispute **in order to** arrange his death.

But since we don't know the reason behind the request, we can't use an *in order to* phrase of any kind.

However, the following statement could make use of an *in order to* rephrasing:

> He was asked to resolve the dispute to settle the score.
>   → He was asked to resolve the dispute **in order to** settle the score.

---

> He was believed to use our sympathy to reach his goal.

Your rephrasing of this sentence replaces the wrong **to**. You have to ask yourself what the *purpose* of something is:

> ✘ He was believed **in order to** use our sympathy to reach his goal.
>   ✔ He was believed to use our sympathy **in order to** reach his goal.